# redirectTo variable in the LoginController is being ignored and always redirecting back to "/"

Tags: php, laravel

No matter what I put in to the redirectTo variable in the LoginController is being ignored and always going to the "/" route. The same redirectTo in the RegisterController works fine. Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this? My LoginController code is below:

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/welcome';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

And my routes:

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/welcome', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->name('welcome');
```

Comment: Where are you using the $redirectTo? Paste entire code please

Comment: Could you please also paste your routes (web.php)

Comment: You set a variable, but you dont use it anywhere??

Comment: I'm just using standard laravel authentication. I included the web.php file above. In the RegisterController if I change the $redirectTo variable it will go to that route when the user registers but when I change it in the LoginController it just gets ignored.

Comment: Have you changed your `Authenticate` middleware at all? If so, can you post it please?

Comment: I haven't changed anything in the Authenticate middleware. This is a fresh install of laravel. All I want it to do is redirect to /welcome when the user logs in but it keeps going to "/". And the strange thing is when I remove the "/" route it works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

If the redirect path needs custom generation logic you may define a redirectTo method instead of a redirectTo property:

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
     return '/path';
}
```

You need to use redirectTo property as shown above it will work.use [laravel authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication) for more details

Comment: I have added this to the LoginController and it still goes to the "/" route.

Comment: @TheHerndog you should modify the `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware's `handle` method to use your new URI when redirecting the user...try this and let me know further.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `redirectPath` method:

```
protected function redirectPath()
{
    return route('welcome');
}
```

This works when you import and use the `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers` trait. Using this method also gives the ability to add logic and for example redirect to different routes for different user roles.

When you are using the `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware, add this to the `handle` method:

```
if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
    return redirect('/welcome');
}

return $next($request);
```

Comment: I put this in to my LoginController and it still redirects to "/".

Comment: @TheHerndog I've edited the answer. The RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware might be triggered.